# General form of solution to given ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I consider the following ODE:
$$ crx^2 f''(x) + r x f'(x) - a f(x) = 0, $$
where $a, c, r$ are positive constants.

I wonder about the form of its solution depending on the parameter $a$.

I know that for $a=r$ the solution is given by:
$$
f(x) = k_1 x^{-\frac{1}{c}} + k_2 x,
$$
for some positive constants $k_1, k_2$.

I also checked what WolframAlpha suggests me about the solution. It gives:
$$
f(x) = k_1 x^{\frac{i \sqrt{a}\left(-\sqrt{-\frac{cr}{a} - \frac{r}{ac} + \frac{2r}{a} - 4} - \frac{i(c\sqrt{r} - \sqrt{r})}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{c}}\right)}{2\sqrt{c}\sqrt{r}}} + k_2 x^{\frac{i \sqrt{a}\left(\sqrt{-\frac{cr}{a} - \frac{r}{ac} + \frac{2r}{a} - 4} - \frac{i(c\sqrt{r} - \sqrt{r}}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{c}}\right)}{2\sqrt{c}\sqrt{r}}}
$$
for some positive constants $k_1, k_2$.

It is not in line with the formula for $a=r$.

Can anyone suggest me what is the general form of the solution depending on $a$?

Comment: It's Cauchy-Euler's differential  equation. $ax^2y''+bxy'+cy=0$

Comment: Thank you! It is clear for me now.

Comment: Yw...MathMen .....